# How to make icon-based clan name in CoD Ghost?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

I don't understand how people can hack PS4 games like using 30 perks at once, and treating assault streak like it's support streak (dying doesn't break the streak).

But some of the other ones I'm interested about is how do players change their clan color to Green and other colors, or the latest one I've seen is make them look like Playstation Controller buttons!

[image]

Comment: I haven't played call of duty in a long time, but AFAIK it all requires a modded console, or having someone with a modded console invite you to their clan.  Not sure if this question is a good fit for the site.

Answer (score -1):

To change you clan tag color you must go to the Call of Duty app and go to your clan if your high up in the clan ( Commander or Luitenit Commander) and it should be near the emblem. For the buttons I have to tell you to look it up on youtube I am sure someone has made a video about it.